# How to get constraint errors from OCIErrorGet?

Tags: c++, c, oracle, constraints, oracle-call-interface

Our C++ program is using Oracle and OCI to do its database work. Occasionally, the user will trigger a constraint violation, which we detect and then show an error message from OCIErrorGet. OCIErrorGet returns strings like this:

```
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (MYSCHEMA.CC_MYCONSTRAINT) violated - child record found
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

I am looking for the cleanest way to extract "MYSCHEMA.CC_MYCONSTRAINT" from the Oracle error. Knowing the name of the constraint, I could show a better error message (our code could look up a very meaningful error message if it had access to the constraint name).

I could use a regex or something and assume that the Oracle message will never change, but this seems a little fragile to me. Or I could look for specific ORA codes and then grab whatever text falls between the parentheses. But I was hoping OCI had a cleaner/more robust way, if a constraint fails, to figure out the actual name of the failed constraint without resorting to hardcoded string manipulation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219.pdf), a string search is exactly what you need to do:

> **Recognizing Variable Text in Messages**
>
> To help you find and fix errors, Oracle embeds object names, numbers,
>   and character strings in some messages. These embedded variables are
>   represented by string, number, or character, as appropriate. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> ORA-00020: maximum number of processes (number) exceeded
> ```
>
> The preceding message might actually appear as follows:
>
> ```
> ORA-00020: maximum number of processes (50) exceeded
> ```

Oracle makes a big point in their docs of saying the strings will be kept up to date in their section on "Message Accuracy."  It's a pretty strong suggestion that they intend you to do a string search.

Also, according to [this website](http://www.rampant-books.com/t_gogala_easyphp_handling_errors.htm), the Oracle Error structure also pretty strongly implies that they intend you to do a string search, because the data structure lacks anything else for you to get:

```
array(4) {
   ["code"]=>int(942)
   ["message"]=>string(40) "ORA-00942: table or view does not  exist"
   ["offset"]=>int(14)
   ["sqltext"]=>string(32) "select * from non_existing_table" 
}
```

> This output reveals the following information:
>
> - The variable $erris an array with four elements.
> - The first element is accessible by the key ‘code’ and its value is    number 942.
> - The second value is accessible by the key ‘message’ and the value is    string “ORA-00942: table or view does not exist”.
> - The third value is accessible by the key ‘offset’, and its value is    the number 14. This is the character before the name of the
>     non-existing table.
> - The fourth member is the problematic SQL message causing the error in    the first place.

I agree with you; it would be great if there were a better way to get the constraint name you're violating, but string-matching seems to be the intended way.

Comment: Thanks for investigating. I've dropped in a regular expression and it works okay in practice.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still very fragile. Once user changes NLS_LANG and selects one of other "over 9000" languages, this approach may fall apart =(